# confusing database profiler output in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I set database profiling in MongoDB to level 1 and slowms to 500 millis. I ran the aggregate command on 'questions' collection but the namespace field (ns) in the profiler output is showing 'dummydb.subjects' but command.aggregate is showing my query ran on questions collections.

In documentation it says, "ns" is the namespace that operation targets. So, Why an aggregate query running on 'questions' collection targeting 'subjects' collection.

I've seen the same behavior with other aggregation queries too.

I've attached a sample profiler output for reference.

```
{
"op" : "command",
"ns" : "dummydb.subjects",
"command" : {
    "aggregate" : "questions",
    "pipeline" : [
        {"$match" : {
            "user" : ObjectId("5d428873722f2f1acc0dc382"),
            "state" : {"$ne" : 4}
            }
        }, 
        {"$lookup" : {
            "from" : "subjects",
            "let" : {"sid" : "$subject"},
            "pipeline" : [
                {"$match" : {"$expr" : {"$eq" : ["$_id","$$sid"]}}},
                {"$project" : {"_id" : 0,"name" : 1}}
                ],
            "as" : "subject_name"
            }
        },
        {"$unwind" : {"path" : "$subject_name"}},
        {"$addFields" : {"subject_name" : "$subject_name.name"}},
        {"$sort" : {"_id" : -1}}

    ],
    "cursor" : {},
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1565671762, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"hVRzmv/pTffGvoo2ZMdng4aF1PA="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong("6707648170752475137")
        }
    },
    "lsid" : {"id" : UUID("b80d4d58-c627-4e9f-85df-f705d62c79db")}                
},
"keysExamined" : 175,
"docsExamined" : 175,
"hasSortStage" : true,
"numYield" : 41,
"nreturned" : 101,
"responseLength" : 86128,
"protocol" : "op_query",
"millis" : 1079,
"planSummary" : "IXSCAN { user: 1 }",
}
```